# Efficient way to re-assign char pointers to char arrays

Tags: arrays, pointers

I am dealing with char arrays and pointers to the arrays.

```
char firstAr[10] = "First";
char secondAr[10] = "Second";
char thirdAr[10] = "Third";

char* arPtrOne = firstAr;
char* arPtrTwo = secondAr;
char* arPtrThree = thirdAr;
```

I also have a second set of char arrays

```
char fourthAr[10] = "Fourth";
char fifthAr[10] = "Fifth";
char sixthAr[10] = "Sixth";
```

The above char arrays and char pointers can’t be altered (I have to work with them). I need to change the char arrays that my pointers point to, so that they now point to the second set of char arrays. I know I can do this by doing the following,

```
arPtrOne = fourthAr;
arPtrTwo = fifthAr;
arPtrThree = sixthAr;
```

This is fine for my example above but if I had 100 array I would need 100 statements to point them all to new char arrays. I am hoping someone could help me find a more efficient way to do this for my example above.

To stop any duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions discover all the relevant information, This was also posted here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=529860.0

Comment: I think you got an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, so maybe tell us a little more about what you want to do at all. It can be super twisted or easy-peasy, depending on the context.

Comment: Hi Downvoter, I purposely didn’t include what I am trying to achieve because when I do people suggest alternate ways to do it and the code I am working on is already written and CANNOT be changed. Even when I say this in a post the first comment is always, “why not try it this way” etc. which is of no use even though peoples ideas and intent are good, I made it this specific because this is all I need to know.  Since you asked though, my issue is that I am working on code that is already written to display a fixed set of char strings using a lot of complicated classes, methods etc. (1/3)

Comment: To display the char strings it uses the char pointers to the char arrays. I need to display the strings in a different language (French etc.) without changing any of the display classes or functions. As the pre written code uses the char pointers to display the char arrays and I can’t change that,  I need to point the pointers at new French char arrays that I add myself. I have got this working correctly using statements (arPtrOne = fourthAr;) but to move all the pointers to all the French character arrays I would need a statement for each one and there are hundreds. (2/3)

Comment: So I am trying to find a better way to point the pointers I have at the new char arrays(French ones) again bearing in mind that it needs to be the pointers I already have that point at the new text as these are the ones referenced by all the classes, methods, calls etc. (3/3)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `char**`?

```
char* l_arry[100];
```

You can:

```
l_arry[0] = //your first string;
l_arry[1] = //your second string;
l_arry[2] = //your third string;
```

Comment: Again as with all other suggestions so far I cant change the char array pointers, I have to use these exact (already delcared) pointer to point to the new char arrays. I would love to do it a normal way and use an array of char pointers, that hold the char strings and use enums to index them in a for loop where I just shift through the array etc. but I CANT change the pointers, I have to use the exact  ones in the example.

Answer (score 0):

As I could not figure out how to point the existing pointers at the new char inside a loop I decided to fill the original arrays with the new char arrays contents. To do this I created all of the new char arrays inside an array char pointers so that I could reference them in a for loop. I then created a new array of char * and pointed them to the original arrays. I then used a strcpy inside a for loop to copy the contents of the new array to the original. This means that the original pointers remain unaltered and still point to the original arrays but now the arrays have updated contents. This has the same effect as pointing the pointers at new c arrays without having to actually do so.

```
char firstAr[10] = "First";
char secondAr[10] = "Second";
char thirdAr[10] = "Third";

char* arPtrOne = firstAr;
char* arPtrTwo = secondAr;
char* arPtrThree = thirdAr;

char *newStrings[3][10]=
{
    "Fourth",
    "Fifth",
    "Sixth"
};

char *newPtrs[3]=
{
    firstAr,
    secondAr,
    thirdAr
};


for(int i = 0; i<3;i++)
{
    strcpy (newPtrs[i], newStrings[i]); 
}
```